# Is it okay to push users from an inadequate forum to a far superior forum?

Tags: discussion, forum

So I am browsing the interwebs and came across a rather ugly, poorly designed, under used (a few posts a week) SharePoint forum. Is it okay for me to point users from there to the amazing SPExchange? I was thinking of at least adding it to my signature, or even reply to some issues and say, go ask it over there. Or is this bad etiquette?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to post links to answers here (where appropriate).

That way you're promoting the site and demonstrating its usefulness, while also avoiding treading on anyone's toes.

Comment: Love this idea, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that depends on the etiquette of the other forum. I suspect they might not appreciate it, particularly if you do it a lot, or in a very obvious way.

Comment: Yeah, its the obvious piece... and worst case they block my account, oh darn.

Comment: +1 maybe ask the admin? I'm assuming the forum was created to help users get answers so perhaps we can combine forces!